# How do I solve a double integral with an absolute value?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the following integral

$$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^1|x-y|(6x^2y) \, dx \, dy$$

how do I change the limits of integration?

According to my textbook, it is

$$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y}^{1}(x-y)(6x^2y) \, dx \, dy +\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^y (y-x)(6x^2y)\,dx\,dy$$

How did the textbook get the new limits of integration? Can someone explain to me he steps I should use?

Comment: It separated the cases where $|x-y|=x-y$ from those where $|x-y|=y-x$, i.e. those where $x \ge y$ from those where $x \le y$ (since those where $x=y$ have measure $0$)

Comment: But how did they determine the new limits of integration?

Comment: The first range for $x$ covers the values for which $x \ge y$ and $x \in [0,1]$. The second range for $x$ covers the values for which $x \le y$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the x integral for fixed $y$:

$$\int_{x=0}^{1}|x-y|(6x^2y)dx = \int_{x=0}^{y}|x-y|(6x^2y)dx + \int_{x=y}^{1}|x-y|(6x^2y)dx$$

$$=\int_{x=0}^{y}(y-x)(6x^2y)dx + \int_{x=y}^{1}(x-y)(6x^2y)dx$$

Answer (score 7):

By exchanging the $x$-variable and the $y$-variable:
$$\iint_{(0,1)^2}|x-y|x^2 y\,dx\,dy = \iint_{(0,1)^2}|x-y|y^2 x\,dx\,dy$$
hence we just need to compute:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}I&=&3\iint_{(0,1)^2}|x-y|xy(x+y)\,dx\,dy = 6\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}xy(x^2-y^2)\,dy\,dx\\&=&6\int_{0}^{1}x^5\int_{0}^{1}z(1-z^2)\,dz\,dx=6\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Nice demonstration of the power that exploiting symmetry brings!  +1

Comment: I appreciate that you calculated the integral exactly, but I don't understand the steps. How does $I$ relate to the initial integral? I assume they are equivalent, but I don't understand how.

Comment: @МатиТернер: $I$ *equals* the initial integral, by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this, you are giving a two dimensional input in $~xy~$ plane (if you visualize total input area is a square of side $~1~$) and getting output of your function assume $~z=f(x)~$ on $~z~$ axis.

We have to calculate the total volume.

Small volume is $~(z~dx~dy )~$.

Now mod is over $~x-y~$ so draw its graph on our input $~xy~$ plane it divides in two area if $~x-y<0~$ then mod opens with negative sign and $~x-y >0~$ then it opens directly.

Now you divide your integration in two parts and simply put limit like you do in simple double integral.

Hope it helped.

Comment: its not about answer man,its about different approaches . i was not trying to give answer i was showing different method and visualization.it is not about just one question.there is no competition man.there can be many ways to solve a question and each way give you different angles to think

Comment: and one more thing, i am new here

Comment: I am fully aware you are new, which is why you probably don't understand how MSE works. Answers are used to answer the question. If you don't want to do so, you can make your own question and answer it yourself to share knowledge not in a Q&A format.