# Double integral with absolute - changing variables?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to do the following integral:
$$I=\int^l_0 dt \int^l_0 ds e^{-|t-s|/\zeta_p}$$
I know the answer to be:
$$2\zeta_p^2\left(e^{-l/\zeta_p}-1+\frac{l}{\zeta_p}\right)$$
and I know it can be done using the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370538/how-do-i-solve-a-double-integral-with-an-absolute-value), but I want to do it via changing variables. So I letting:
$$x=t-s$$
$$y=t+s$$
we get
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int^{2l}_0 dy \int^{l}_{-l} dx e^{-|x|/\zeta_p}$$
where the $1/2$ comes from the Jacobian. On integrating this however I get:
$$I=2l \int^{l}_{0} dx e^{-x/\zeta_p}$$
$$=2l \zeta_p(1-e^{-l/\zeta_p})$$
which is clearly not the correct answer. My question is therefore, what is wrong with the method I have outlined here such that it does not work?

---

<sub>Physical content: The integral here represents the mean distance of a worm like chain of persistence length $\zeta_p$.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure $\frac{1}{2}\int^{2l}_0 dy \int^{l}_{-l} dx e^{-|x|/\zeta_p}$ is correct? I am getting a different answer. I did a quick back of the envelope calculation with the new region of integration a rectangle with vertices $(0,0), (l,l),(0,2l),(-l,l)$ Then, using symmetry, I integrated $y$ from $x$ to $-x+2l$, then integrated $x$ from $0$ to $l$ and multiplied the result by two.

Comment: @ Quantum: great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the calculation:

(I.) The new region of integration $R$, is a rectangle with vertices $(0,0),(l,l),(0,2l),(−l,l)$ and the Jacobian is, as you say, $1/2.$

(II.) Now, using symmetry, integrate your function $f$, from $y=x$ to $y=−x+2l$, then integrate $x$ from $0$ to $l$ and multiply the result by two:

$2\left ( \frac{1}{2}\iint_R fdydx \right )=\int_{0}^{l}\int_{x}^{-x+2l}fdydx.$